# django-cors-headers not working: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: python, django, cors, django-cors-headers

Full error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://[redacted]/api/get_match_urls/' from origin 'https://trello.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I am making an API call from an extension while at trello.com

I have `corsheaders` in my `INSTALLED_APPS`. I have `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` in my middleware as high up as possible. And I have `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` set to `True`. Yes I've tried the alternate alias `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` and it still didn't work. Anyone have any ideas?

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: does the request contain an Authorization Header?

Comment: yes, with a token

Comment: You cannot have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` when sending Authorization header. You should instead specify a specific domain (in your case it should be `https://trello.com`)

Comment: Also make sure you return `Authorization` is one of the values in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header

Comment: I cannot specify a specific domain. Is there any way around this?

Comment: there is no other way around. But why can't you specify a domain? Maybe you can post a snippet of your middleware

Comment: Because the whole point is to be able to use the extension anywhere. I don't have any custom middleware settings, except for corsheaders' code which isn't mine. I've updated my post to include my `MIDDLEWARE` settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look at the `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` and it seems if you set `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` and not `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` it will return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, but if you also set `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` then it will return the origin from the request headers.

here is the part of the code that does that

```
origin = request.META.get("HTTP_ORIGIN")

# omiting the lines in between

if conf.CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS and not conf.CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS:
    response[ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN] = "*"
else:
    response[ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN] = origin
```

another idea would be also to use `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES` e.g

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
    r".*",
]
```

Comment: I set `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` and `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` to `True` and that didn't work. I also replaced `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` with your `CORS ALLOWED ORIGIN_REGEXES` and that didn't work either. By "didn't work" I mean I got the same error as in the OP. Thanks for your help, though -- it really seems like it should work. You did good digging. I should say I'm using django-cors-headers==3.6.0

Comment: I think there should be a way to make it work, it is the server that decides who should be allowed to do requests to it, and you have control over that. But I would need to do more digging. Would be nice if you could give a small working snippet (a simplified version of your code)

Comment: This fixed things. The error I was getting is unrelated to CORS (wrong url endpoint)

Answer (score 3):

Could not make it work after trying everything mentioned here. In fact, everything mentioned in the django-cors-headers documentation was already there in my settings.py.

After a lot of digging in, I found out the culprit was the "MIDDLEWARE" definition itself in settings.py. According to my version of django (which is 1.7) it needs to be "MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES" and not "MIDDLEWARE". You can find this out when you look at the django documentation for middlewares which can be found here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/ (don't forget to choose your version of django from right bottom corner). When this change was done, my preflights started returning the needed response headers.

Still scratching my head thinking how simple was the solution (when found out) for an issue which took hours away from me :(